# Not ACK bit in the AT24C512C EEPROM Read operation via I2C connection

Tags: i2c, atmel, eeprom

As you can see in the below picture of the AT24C512C datasheets from ATMEL,after reading desired data from EEPROM,there is a NOT ACK bit following the data which I don't understand is produced by the EEPROM or MCU(master)?
As you know past ACK bits in the writing data to EEPROM was produced by EEPROM to acknowledging a correct data receiving.[Reading section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BXB3.gif)

Answer (score 0):

NOT ACK bit is produced by MCU (master) to generate stop condition here and if there is any error while slave receiving the data then it would be hardware generated by the slave or you can say EEPROM. It is a two-way communication.

If you are using this module I will suggest you to use random read by providing the address on ehich data is written and you read the same address. Then , it would work. It would be similar to codes in the following link. You can choose the language as per the mcu you are using.
https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity/AT24HC02C